# Regex with last match only

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying write a regex to get last digit.

> My string: name[0][0].
>
> My regex: str.match(/d+/g)

It return all match. Can you help me make regex return only last match?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the last digit,

```
\d(?=\D*$)
```

To get the last number.

```
\d+(?=\D*$)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/wX9fR1/3)

`\d+` matches one or more digits. `+` repeats the previous token or more times. `(?=\D*$)` called positive lookahead assertion which asserts that the match would be followed by any number of non-digit characters further followed by end of the line.

Comment: Also Thanks for your explain. I need to learn more about regex.